# Using NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType context as parentContext

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Can I set a NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType context as other context's parentContext? something like:

```
context1 = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

context2 = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
context2.parentContext = context1;

// Is it OK for context3?
context3 = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
context3.parentContext = context2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, There is nothing wrong with that.  You can chain them together as much as you want.